# openCL - difference in handling array and scalar

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to dig into openCL. At the moment I'm asking myself why a scalar differs from array when it comes to transferring to GPU.

Below there are two inputs. A scalar and a array. Why is there such a big difference in transferring them to the GPU?

Thanks in advance!

```
// input size
int input_size = 4;
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(unsigned int), &_input_size);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set kernel arguments!");
}

// input
int input[input_size];
input[0] = 1;
input[1] = 2;
input[2] = 3;
input[3] = 4;
cl_mem cl_input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int) * _input_size, NULL, NULL);
if (!cl_input) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate device memory!");
}
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_input);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set kernel arguments!");
}
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, cl_input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * _input_size, _input, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write to source array!");
}

// output
int output_size = 4;
int output[output_size];
cl_mem cl_output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(int) * _output_size, NULL, NULL);
if (!cl_output) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate device memory!");
}
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_output);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set kernel arguments!" );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure yet but I'm pretty sure it's because an array is not a scalar. On a serious note, I have absolutely no clue what you are asking.

Comment: I wanna try to write some c++ templated insert functions to handle in-/output to/from opencl in background. If a array needs other treatment than scalar my template function idea is not realisable.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCL scalars are passed  by value and are constants to each thread. Arrays  are passed by reference (address)  and can be used  a input (read only) , output ( write only) or input/output ( read/write). Arrays require  the cl_mem object be passed as the arguments. cl_mem is a meta object that describes the array. Scalars are so simple they just require their size as meta data.

So in you above example  the kernel should look like ....

```
kernel void mykernel( const int arg0,  global int * arg1, global int * arg2 ... ) {
    int  i =  get_global_id(0);

    // In every thread arg0  is constant value and cannot be changed

    if (i < arg0)
        arg2[i] = arg[1[i];
}
```